# clang binary with debug symbol is too big

Tags: c++, clang++

I made simple c++ source file.

source file is :

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and built it including debug symbol.

when using clang, binary size is 100kb

but using gcc, binary size is 19kb.

I tryed "readelf -wi hello_clang"

```
<4><22b>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_member)
<22c>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string) __fmtflags_
<230>   DW_AT_type        : <0x5e>
<234>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 2
<235>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 362 
readelf: dwarf_loclist_form_expr_b: Invalid argument [dwarf_loclist_from_expr_b(279)]
<237>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0 byte block:   ()
<4><23a>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_member)
<23b>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string) __precision_
<23f>   DW_AT_type        : <0x799>
<243>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 2
<244>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 363
readelf: dwarf_loclist_form_expr_b: Invalid argument [dwarf_loclist_from_expr_b(279)]
<246>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0 byte block:   ()
<4><249>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_member)
<24a>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string) __width_
<24e>   DW_AT_type        : <0x799>
<252>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 2
<253>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 364
readelf: dwarf_loclist_form_expr_b: Invalid argument [dwarf_loclist_from_expr_b(279)]
<255>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0 byte block:   ()
<4><258>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_member)
<259>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string) __rdstate_
<25d>   DW_AT_type        : <0x183>
<261>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 2
<262>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 365
readelf: dwarf_loclist_form_expr_b: Invalid argument [dwarf_loclist_from_expr_b(279)]
<264>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0 byte block:   ()
<4><267>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_member)
<268>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string) __exceptions_
<26c>   DW_AT_type        : <0x183>
<270>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 2
<271>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 366
readelf: dwarf_loclist_form_expr_b: Invalid argument [dwarf_loclist_from_expr_b(279)]
<273>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0 byte block:   ()
<4><276>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_member)
<277>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string) __rdbuf_
<27b>   DW_AT_type        : <0x4dda>
<27f>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 2
<280>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 367
readelf: dwarf_loclist_form_expr_b: Invalid argument [dwarf_loclist_from_expr_b(279)]
<282>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 0 byte block:   ()
<4><285>: Abbrev Number: 9 (DW_TAG_member)
<286>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string) __loc_
<28a>   DW_AT_type        : <0x4dda>
<28e>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 2
<28f>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 368
```

this message is repeatedly output.

what does this message mean?

Why this problem happen?

Is this clang bug?

How is it possible to reduce the binary size?

My environment:
i386, freebsd11, clang38

Comment: please post your output-texts as actual *text*, not as image.

Comment: too long , so i can't post 
source code is simple

Comment: don't put it in a comment. edit your original post to include the code and make sure you have proper formatting.

Comment: Sorry, shortly after the start i didn't know well

Comment: You don't show the exact compilation command, and you really should.

Comment: compilation command so simple.
"clang++ -g -o hello_clang hello.cpp"

Answer (score 0):

I am not observing, on my Debian/Sid/x86-64 box with GCC-6.2 and Clang-3.8, sizes consistent with your observations:

Notice that your example should have `#include <iostream>` before the `main`.

Notice also that `g++` and `clang++` are accepting `-g0` or `-g1` or `-g2` or `-g3` (and you can mix that with `-O0` or `-O1` or `-O2`)

```
 g++ -g0 -O0 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-gcc-g0O0
 clang++ -g0 -O0 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-clang-g0O0
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   9064 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-clang-g0O0
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   9008 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-gcc-g0O0
 g++ -g0 -O1 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-gcc-g0O1
 clang++ -g0 -O1 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-clang-g0O1
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   9488 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-clang-g0O1
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   8840 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-gcc-g0O1
 g++ -g0 -O2 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-gcc-g0O2
 clang++ -g0 -O2 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-clang-g0O2
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   9144 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-clang-g0O2
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   8840 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-gcc-g0O2
 g++ -g1 -O0 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-gcc-g1O0
 clang++ -g1 -O0 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-clang-g1O0
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   10096 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-clang-g1O0
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   10008 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-gcc-g1O0
 g++ -g1 -O1 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-gcc-g1O1
 clang++ -g1 -O1 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-clang-g1O1
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   10848 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-clang-g1O1
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   10888 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-gcc-g1O1
 g++ -g1 -O2 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-gcc-g1O2
 clang++ -g1 -O2 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-clang-g1O2
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   11024 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-clang-g1O2
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   11176 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-gcc-g1O2
 g++ -g2 -O0 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-gcc-g2O0
 clang++ -g2 -O0 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-clang-g2O0
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   16072 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-clang-g2O0
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   28536 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-gcc-g2O0
 g++ -g2 -O1 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-gcc-g2O1
 clang++ -g2 -O1 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-clang-g2O1
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   20864 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-clang-g2O1
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   31024 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-gcc-g2O1
 g++ -g2 -O2 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-gcc-g2O2
 clang++ -g2 -O2 jinmoo.cc -o jinmoo-clang-g2O2
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   20712 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-clang-g2O2
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 basile   basile   31344 Oct 14 15:20 jinmoo-gcc-g2O2
```

I do agree that we don't have the same OS and the same architecture (mine is 64 bits).